# feigenbaum constant

Tags: chaos-theory

how can i predict a chaos with feigenbaum constant in the logistic map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://www.physics.mq.edu.au/~wardle/PHYS220/chaos.ppt) (*Chaos and the Logistic Map Lecture Notes* by Lesa Moore).

Comment: a minor suggestion I have is that, instead of typing "See this", it would be slightly more informative to say something like "See the lecture notes of So-and-So on this topic". This way we don't have to mouse over the link to get an idea of where it is pointing to.

Comment: @TonyK: Trevor [should pay attention to Willie](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/155585).

Comment: @TonyK: that was extremely rude, and I disagree.  There are plenty of reasons to include more information when you give links, including the fact that it makes the content of those links searchable for future users.

Comment: I don't think this link exists anymore